# Ubuntu 16.04: Can only boot in recovery mode

Tags: 16.04, boot, fsck

What happened:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 works fine.
2. Emergency in our building → computer was forced to shut down immediately.
3. Since then: Ubuntu doesn't boot properly:

   - Screen stays gray not black before login screen appears
   - Recovery mode → `fsck` → Resume boot → Everything works fine

What I found in `journalctl` boot logs:

```
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda2: Resize inode not valid.
/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

I guess I need to run:

```
fsck -a /dev/sda2
```

Can it harm my system in any way? Do I need to unmount `sda2` first?

`fdisk -l` says:

```
/dev/sda1      2048    1126399    1124352  549M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1126400    3174399    2048000 1000M BIOS boot
/dev/sda3   3174400   35942399   32768000 15.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  35942400 7501475839 7465533440  3.5T Microsoft basic data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filesystem is inconsistent, so you need to run `fsck` as you write. It's best to unmount `/dev/sda2` if possible, or boot from a Live media, and then do `fsck`.

Will it harm? It will bring your filesystem back to a consistent state, clearing dangling inodes and blocks. You will probably not lose data, unless your disk is severely crashed, but then data is probably lost anyway.

A good backup from yesterday is always a good asset to have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little bit confused now. When I say ```fsck -A /dev/sda2``` it says ```/dev/sda4 is mounted``` and  ```WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage. Do you want to continue?``` I don't want to damage /dev/sda4, I only want to repair /dev/sda2.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought that you where in GRUB shell. The best to unmount /dev/sda2 if possible, or boot from a Live media, and then do fsck. I don't think that you will  damage the filesystem by doing it on the mounted device, if you reboot immediately after.

Comment: It worked when I tried it in GRUB shell.